# Im having an error when I click my last fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I cant access the last fragment (case 7) in my app. I've been debugging it and I think it's a logical error but I'm having a hard time to fix it. The part in

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.section_titles);
    if (number >= 1) {
        mTitle = stringArray[number-1];
    }
}
```

So here is the part my code derived from the default Navigation drawer in android studio:

```
 @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position+1){
        case 1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickReserveSeat.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickCancelSeat.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickMyTrips.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickUserAccount.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickLogout.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickHelp.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickAboutUs.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;
    }
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.section_titles);
    if (number >= 1) {
        mTitle = stringArray[number-1];
    }
}
```

onClickAboutUs (Last Fragment Class/Method)

```
public class onClickAboutUs extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public static onClickAboutUs newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    onClickAboutUs fragment = new onClickAboutUs();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
public onClickAboutUs() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container,
            false);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((UserAccount) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
            ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
```

}

EDIT: (logcat)

```
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
        at com.oop.admin.reserbus.UserAccount.onSectionAttached(UserAccount.java:120)
        at com.oop.admin.reserbus.onClickAboutUs.onAttach(onClickAboutUs.java:37)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:907)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what error... paste logcat..

Comment: can you post the code of anything.newInstance(position + 1) along with the portion where you are calling onSessionAttached method

Comment: have checked the title for another fragment are reflected properly? For your Fragment 7 your are getting error in onSessionAttachedMethod bcoz the number might be 8 check print a log there and check?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
      int pos = position+1;

      switch(pos){
      case 1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, onClickReserveSeat.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
            break;

... 
}
```

Comment: where you call onSectionAttached method ? I think error is inside it

Comment: The same in the edited post. The logic from onSectionAttached and calling the onAttach method in the last fragment class.